# YouTube Analytics API

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I am newbie for Google apis and wanted to start on working YouTube Analytics API to generate reports.I have created project in side Google developer console.When I click on credentials there are two options - OAuth  and Public API access .I am not able to understand with which way I should go OAuth or Public API access .For OAuth while creating new client id there are three options - Web application,Service Account and Installed application so here also which is recommended way ?Please help me to understand this things.

Note : Our requirement is to use YouTube Analytics API to generate reports for uploaded videos on our clients channel.

Comment: hey ,can any one help me about question mentioned above ?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to private user data, OAuth 2.0 is the recommended authorization method for the Analytics API. If you're collecting and storing data to be used on your end, you most likely want to go with the server-side application approach.

From the documentation:

> - The **server-side** flow supports web applications that can securely store persistent information.
> - The **client-side** flow supports JavaScript applications running in a browser.
> - The **installed application** flow supports applications installed on a device, such as a phone or computer.

From the documentation on the service account option:

> The **service account** flow supports server-to-server interactions that do not access user information. However, **the YouTube Analytics API does not support this flow**. Since there is no way to link a Service Account to a YouTube account, attempts to authorize requests with this flow will generate an error.

There's a lot of documentation on all of these options provided to you, I'd recommend reading through it in its entirety to make sure you have a firm grasp on the concepts. [Click here to read about OAuth 2.0 with the YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/authentication)

Cheers!

**Edit:** Just to be completely clear, if you're collecting data through a backend application, use the "Service Account" option for generating OAuth Client IDs. If, however, you're having a interact with the API reports through a web/installed application, you would select "Web/Installed Application". I hope this was helpful and clear.

Comment: I don't understand: you are saying 'if you're collecting data through a backend application, use the "Service Account" option for generating OAuth Client IDs', however above that you quote docs that say that YouTube Analytics API does not support service account flow.

Comment: Good point @giac_man. I know from experience that even though the documentation for both the Data API and Analytics API say you cannot use the service account flow, it does in fact work if you are a Youtube partner or MCN, which I am.

With that being said, the Analytics API has been deprecated by YouTube, and they recommend you use the Reporting API now.

Comment: @NickKnuckle Is it possible for you to share your authorization code snippet with a service account? I'm having a heck of a time  with this...

Comment: @CSharpMinor Hey! The package has been updated many times since I wrote this answer, so the code I wrote (and still use) is using an outdated syntax. I'd suggest reading through [this doc](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-server.md) from the googleapi github page, if you're using python. 

If you're using a different language, find the link for your preferred language's API [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/guides/auth/service-accounts) (at the bottom of the page).

I hope that helps!

Comment: @NickKnuckle no worries pal, I'm on .NET, I just rolled my own with HttpClient, no biggie.

Comment: @CSharpMinor I should have known, given your username :P NIce work

Answer (score 0):

After creating a project from developer console you can try to following [this tutorial](https://www.araclouds.com/diy-tutoriaux/897-tutoriel-youtube-analytics-api-c-forms/) (in french), at the bottom there is the complete fuction for reporting everything from the Youtube API analytics.

here is the function to get data from both Youtube API and Youtube analytics API

don't forget to add your client_secrets.json to your \bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1

```
    public async void FetchYoutubeAnalyticsAPI()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
            );
        }

        var youTubeAnalyticsService = new YouTubeAnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });

        var request = youTubeAnalyticsService.Reports.Query();
        request.StartDate = ("2019-01-01");
        request.EndDate = ("2020-09-30");
        request.Ids = ("channel==UCmLQ3sdAd6CypJIne5ZANaA");
        request.Metrics = ("views,comments,likes,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration");
      
        QueryResponse requestquery = request.Execute();

        List<int> myChannelDataList = new List<int>();

        int listsize = 0;
        foreach (object obj in requestquery.Rows[0])
        { 
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
            myChannelDataList.Add(value);
      /*      Debug.WriteLine("Value : " + value);
            Debug.WriteLine("LISTE / " + myChannelDataList[0]);
            Debug.WriteLine("Count : " + myChannelDataList.Count);*/
            listsize = myChannelDataList.Count;
        }
        List<string> metrics = new List<string> { "Vues", "Commentaires", "Likes", "Dislike", "Minutes", "MoyenneTemps" };
        for (int i = 0; i < listsize; i++)
        {
            Label labels = new Label();
            labels.Top = (i + 4) * 20;
            labels.Left = 100;
            labels.AutoSize = true;
            labels.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            labels.Text = metrics[i] + " :" + myChannelDataList[i].ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(labels);
        }


        // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });
        var requestSub = youtubeService.Channels.List("statistics");
        requestSub.Mine = (true);

        ChannelListResponse responsesub = requestSub.Execute();

        foreach (var sresults in responsesub.Items)
        {
            var substats = sresults.Statistics;
            var subcount = substats.SubscriberCount;
            var viewCount = substats.ViewCount;
            var videoCount = substats.VideoCount;
            var commentsCount = substats.CommentCount;

            Debug.WriteLine("SubCount : " + subcount);

            Label labels = new Label();
            labels.Top = 16;
            labels.Left = 280;
            labels.AutoSize = true;
            labels.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            labels.Text = "Subs :" + subcount;
            this.Controls.Add(labels);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Oauth2.0 authentication ,and select web application,this will need to authenticate yourself for the particular channel(as either you are channel owner or contributer) from which you want to retrieve the data.

After authenticating, you can save the token in a file, and it will automatically refresh the token, when the token is expired,use this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64719179/how-to-bypass-entering-authentication-code-to-authorize-my-code-everytime-i-use/64719550#64719550) to save the file.

> [From Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#offline) :
> Access tokens periodically expire and become invalid credentials for a
> related API request. You can refresh an access token without prompting
> the user for permission (including when the user is not present) if
> you requested offline access to the scopes associated with the token.

Do not use service account for Youtube Analytics Api as it is not supported:

> The YouTube Analytics API does not support the service account flow. [From Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization/server-side-web-apps)